# Make instance variable read-only in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to protect an instance variable from being written to/modified in Ruby?

Say I do this:

```
class Test
  def initialize(var)
   @var = var
  end

  def modify
   @var = "test" # This would raise an error, saying '@var' is just readable.
  end
end
```

Is there any way to make instance variable to be read-only? If not, which kind of attribute am I looking for?

Comment: Even constants in ruby are not write-protected. What is your bigger use case which forced you to raise this question?

Comment: Just experimenting with Ruby and wondering quite a lot of things :)

Comment: You must be a C programmer to ask such a question in ruby, I had the same confusions when I started learning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that. First of all, there should not be a reason that a class would need to write-protect an attribute against itself. Secondly, all access protection rules in Ruby, such as it exists, are really only suggestions - ultimately, using introspection, you can access anything you wish, including redefining core methods like `Fixnum#+`. Try this:

```
class Fixnum
  def +(other)
    self - other
  end
end
```

It will mess up your code more than writing to `@var` ever could.

Comment: Don't try it in pry!  It will start spiting some messages in endless loop. btw. `def 2.ff; end`

Answer (score 4):

You *can* virtually protect instance variables with *freezing* a wrapping object:

```
t=Test.new "example"
p t.var
# "example"
t.freeze
t.modify
# :in `modify': can't modify frozen Test (RuntimeError)
p t.var
# t.var is still equal to "example" if exception won't terminate app
```

See [`Object#freeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-freeze) method for details.

Comment: This is impressive answer. I have come up with similar(freezing self) solution. However, you don't protect variables but object of (in this case)class `Test`. You cannot add, delete, modify **pointers** but you can modify *in place* - data that those pointers refer too(C terms). In order to really protect you must freeze variable itself. Check this: https://gist.github.com/nedzadarek/7536766

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this. The closest thing Ruby has to non-writable variables are *constants* which can exist within a class or module and begin with a capital letter (typically all caps). Ruby will not prevent these variables from being written, but will issue a warning if they are redefined.